# Substract specific rows under multiple conditions of a repeated measurement in R

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr, conditional-statements, filtering

I have a `data.frame` with repeated measurements of boars.
Now I need to substract a `data.frame` that only includes measurements if the column "rejected" says "blood" plus the measurement before and the next 3 after the occurence of "blood".
I know that i would have to group it by the boar ID and sort after the time of measurements but i have no idea how to get to the measurement before and after the occurence.

```
dat2 <- dat1 %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  filter(any(reject == "blood")) %>%
  ungroup(ID)
```

I created a `data.frame` with all the repeated measurements of the boars who once had the reject reason "blood". But I dont know how to filter it down to only the 5 measurements (blood, one ahead, three after)

I also can use an ongoing measurement ID instead of the date, incase that makes it easier to work with.
I tried using the `lag` function in `dyplr` but i think i am using the `order_by` incorrectly.

```
dat2%>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  lag(reject=="blood", n=1, order_by = measurement_ID)
```